# Exception during 'super' constructor evaluation

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gxt, google-plugin-eclipse

Can anyone help me with this. I'm getting the error message that says Exception during super constructor evaluation when I try to switch to design mode in eclipse. I'm using gwt 2.5.1 with gxt 2.2.5. When I do not use gxt I'm able to use the design mode. I tried switching different gxt versions. I tried gxt 2.1 - 2.2.4 with no success. I know that it's a compatability problem with gwt and gxt but I do not know which versions of gxt go with gwt 2.5.1 I even dropped down to gwt 2.2.0 with no sucess. I've placed the stack trace below. Any help would be appreciated. Also I'm using

eclipse
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Stack Trace
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 313 (Exception during 'super' constructor evaluation). Window() {} java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DESCRIPTION
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.layout.DefaultLayoutInfo.(DefaultLayoutInfo.java:39)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createDefaultImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:231)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.initialize_createImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:208)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createExposedChildren(LayoutContainerInfo.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create(ThisCreationSupport.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.evaluateJavaInfoUsingCreationSupport(JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.addJavaInfo(JavaInfoParser.java:1261)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager$6.run(UndoManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DESCRIPTION
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.layout.DefaultLayoutInfo.(DefaultLayoutInfo.java:39)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createDefaultImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:231)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.initialize_createImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:208)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createExposedChildren(LayoutContainerInfo.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.JavaInfo.initialize(JavaInfo.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.JavaInfo.setObject(JavaInfo.java:1267)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.ComponentInfo.setObject(ComponentInfo.java:65)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.ContentPanelInfo.setObject(ContentPanelInfo.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create(ThisCreationSupport.java:269)
    ... 36 more

Full context stack trace:
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 313 (Exception during 'super' constructor evaluation). Window() {} java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DESCRIPTION
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.layout.DefaultLayoutInfo.(DefaultLayoutInfo.java:39)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createDefaultImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:231)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.initialize_createImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:208)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createExposedChildren(LayoutContainerInfo.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create(ThisCreationSupport.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.evaluateJavaInfoUsingCreationSupport(JavaInfoEvaluationHelper.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.addJavaInfo(JavaInfoParser.java:1261)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager$6.run(UndoManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DESCRIPTION
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.layout.DefaultLayoutInfo.(DefaultLayoutInfo.java:39)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createDefaultImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:231)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.initialize_createImplicitLayout(LayoutContainerInfo.java:208)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.LayoutContainerInfo.createExposedChildren(LayoutContainerInfo.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.JavaInfo.initialize(JavaInfo.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.JavaInfo.setObject(JavaInfo.java:1267)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.ComponentInfo.setObject(ComponentInfo.java:65)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gxt.model.widgets.ContentPanelInfo.setObject(ContentPanelInfo.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.creation.ThisCreationSupport.create(ThisCreationSupport.java:269)
    ... 36 more

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I had to upgrade my window builder pro to the new beta version on https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro-beta after I did this it worked. I had to drop the gxt version down to 2.1 but I'm not sure that made a big difference in the error. After I added the google plugin install into eclipse indigo I went into help-install new software-already installed software- and I removed everything related to windows builder and gwt designer. Then I rebooted eclipse and installed the beta version of windows builder. I tried it twice and it worked both times.